# If $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2|x_{n+1} - x_n| = 0$, then sequence of real numbers $x_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis

Is the following true?

> If $\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2|x_{n+1} - x_n| = 0$, then sequence of real numbers $x_n$ converges.

I suspect it to be true. If the "if" part is true, then $|x_{n+1}-x_n|$ has to go to zero "faster" than $n^2$. It is true that we have counterexample where $\lim |x_{n+1} - x_n| = 0$ but $x_n$ does not converge. For example, $x_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$. But in this case, $\frac{1}{k}$ does not decrease to zero that fast.

How should I prove the claim, if it's true?

Answer (score 2):

The claim is true. Just show that the sequence $x_n$ is Cauchy. Do this by first arguing that there exists $C>0$ such that
$$|x_{k+1}-x_{k}| < \frac C{k^2}$$
for all $k$. Next, observe that if $m>n$, then
$$|x_m-x_n|\le \sum_{k=n}^{m-1}|x_{k+1}-x_k|\le\sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac C{k^2}.$$
Finally use the fact that the RHS tends to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: I was so close. I suppose that we can change $n^2$ to $n^a$ where $a>1$ and the claim still holds?

Comment: Yes, it does. Try to prove that $\sum \frac1{n^a} < \infty$, if $a > 1$ and repeat the argument.

Comment: @Misakov Right, you just want the final upper bound to be the tail of a convergent series.